# Maven и деплой war на tomcat

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat, maven, war

как maven-ом скомпилировать все классы, разместить файлы в соответствующие папки и собрать все это в war, запустить tomcat и потом задеплоить на tomcat. Как я читал, так и делают. Есть ли где руководство?

Comment: А для совсем новичков - куда эти плагины вставить?
Мне нужно получить war из готового проекта, чтобы полом скормить его Tomcat. Запускай из папки с файлом pom cmd с тектом mvn install< или как то по - другому? у меня ошибки валятся. Спасибо

Answer (score 6):

Давайте по шагам:

1. Для компиляции существует следующий плагин в maven

   ```
      <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
           <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. чтобы собрать war архив вам потребуется другой плагин:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <configuration>
               <warSourceDirectory>web-resources</warSourceDirectory>
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
               <webResources>
                   <resource>
                       <filtering>true</filtering>
                       <directory>./web-resources/</directory>
                   </resource>
               </webResources>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. для запуска `tomcat` так же нужно подключить плагин:

   ```
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>
           <configuration>
               <port>9090</port>
               <path>/</path>
               <warDirectory>/</warDirectory>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```

   Важно! Для того, чтобы команда `tomcat7:run-war` запускалась, требуется в `pom.xml` задать `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Comment: Спасибо) Now я понял.